# PPTP VPN Server issue : server = centOS & client = windows 7

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have a CentOS server configured as a PPTP VPN Server.

The client is a Windows 7 with *"Use default gateway on remote network"* in advanced TCP/IPv4 properties enable. He can connect to CentOS without any problem and can access to:

- The Box of his ISP (`http://192.168.1.254/`)
- The CentOS server
- The website which is hosted by the server (through `http://`)

But he canNOT access any other web service (`google.com or 74.125.230.224`)

I am a beginner with web servers so I do not know what can cause this problem.

- Note 0 : The Windows 7 user must be able to access the whole internet through the CentOS PPTP proxy.
- Note 1 : With *"Use default gateway on remote network"* in advanced TCP/IPv4 UNCHECKED it is the same problem
- Note 2 : With *"Use default gateway on remote network"* in advanced TCP/IPv4 UNCHECKED AND *"disable class based route addition"* CHECKED the Win 7 can access google but with the ISP IP (no use of the VPN...)
  [See Screenshot](http://udgjjq.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pVoE7RDdSsP4u81BYhnLgw1rU7Rv4mkdUDhqnTu-YO3iHAPL-CiwMcMRk7sq4GNN4BkQDxbcd1_qz4tt0jQA63Q/Windows%20VPN%20Client%20Properties%20-%20Use%20or%20not%20Use%20Default%20Gateway%20on%20Remote%20Network.jpg?psid=1)
- Note 3 : I have made a `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and a `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

There was a script in my server which did, at every reboot :
`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and a REMOVE(`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`) ...

I added a startup shell with :

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Everything works like a charm !